# Does ArcGIS Pro support personal geodatabases (mdb)?

Tags: arcgis-pro, personal-geodatabase

Does ArcGIS Pro support mdb or not?

1. In ArcGIS Pro,I can't find anywhere can load data from mdb;
2. I have not find the help page.

Comment: No, Pro doesn't support mdb. Open request to persuade Esri to change their minds: https://community.esri.com/ideas/12662-enable-arcgis-pro-to-access-esri-personal-geodatabases

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick search, I found that [ArcGIS Pro does not support Personal Geodatabase in 64-bit versions of ArcGIS](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01301-01325-001324.htm).

I quoted the following information from the help above:

> Personal geodatabases do not scale well in the 64-bit environment.
>   They cannot be used by 64-bit versions of ArcGIS.

Another source at [ESRI Blog](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/06/analysis-geoprocessing-in-arcgis-pro-frequently-asked-questions/) answers to a question:

> Are both personal and file geodatabases available as data sources for
>   ArcGIS Pro?

The answer is:

> Personal geodatabases are not supported in ArcGIS Pro, so you cannot
>   use personal geodatabase datasets as inputs to geoprocessing tools or
>   create those datasets as outputs.

Comment: @giser_tornado if this has answered your question, please consider marking it as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: "Personal geodatabases do not scale well in the 64-bit environment." For the record, that statement makes *zero* sense at face value. A storage format doesn't scale; the code reading/writing to it needs to scale. In some rare cases, you might consider if the size scales well, but the read/write will prevent it from scaling here long before size becomes a concern. (Storage size is typically one the last things that needs optimizing today; disk space is very plentiful.) Effectively, ESRI is saying, "We can't write efficient code for it."

Comment: I would not have written this as "do not scale well..." but the idea that there are no concerns about storage format size is flat out false. Individual formats have limits especially when designed in another era. Specifically Access DBs over about 1 GB have very poor performance. At 2 GB you'll likely see storage failures (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785851/access-mdb-do-access-mdb-files-have-an-upper-size-limit). This is a general problem with the format. The primary libraries used for updating MDBs do not have 64bit equivalents and that is the main reason they're not supported.

Comment: @jpmc26 Esri doesn't provide the drivers for Access interface, Microsoft does (or doesn't, in this case)

Answer (score 0):

So there's a way to do it with ODBC, but I'm not sure yet if ArcGIS Pro knows what to do with it once it's loaded. That's my next mystery. See the following link for instructions:

- `https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-connect-microsoft-access-database-to-arcgis-pro/`

Notes how it worked for me using the above link:

- I downloaded the 64 bit driver (from microsoft) for 64 bit computer (as per instructions)
- The "Microsoft ODBC Administrator" application was called "ODBC Data Sources (64-Bit)" and comes already installed with windows (search for it locally).

Picture of the `.mdb` database loaded in 64-bit ArcGIS Pro:

[image: Screenshot of proof of ArcGIS Pro accessing a .mdb access database on a 64 Bit windows machine]